# One to cure a disease

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I can see a disease that no one else can perceive,
>
> I have the cure and showed it so others would believe.
>
> Through my mask I've seen it spread for centuries,
>
> with just one touch I can solve everyone's miseries.
>
> Though I'm locked up kept away to cure their sickness,
>
> they are afraid of my process and call it wickedness.

Who am I?

Comment: I just tidied up the spelling - if it was a deliberate misspelling as part of the puzzle feel free to roll back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might just be a far too literal interpretation of what I'm reading, but my first instinct tells me it's:

> [SCP-049](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-049)

Comment: Correct this was exactly what I had in mind :)

Comment: What is this? some sort of game?

Comment: @DavidG. there is a game of it but (but originally it's stories) it's called the SCP foundation. They are a made up foundation that keep dangerous entities captive to secure the world from being destroyed. If you like science fiction and horror it is a must read, everyone can create their own story about entities and post them if they are accepted they will be called SCP- and a number, you can read more here if your interested: http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-series personal favourite for me is 106.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Death

and the disease itself is

> Life

```
I can see a disease that no one else can perceive,
```

> Death sees life as a problem.

```
I have the cure and showed it so others would believe.
```

> The cure for life is its ending, via death.  Death comes to all and "cure"s them.

```
Through my mask I've seen it spread for centuries,
```

> "mask" I'm not positive about, but it could be a reference to a degree of isolation, or just that Death may present a face if personified.  Death has perceived life spreading for ages.

```
with just one touch I can solve everyone's miseries.
```

> One touch of death and life is cured.

```
Though I'm locked up kept away to cure their sickness,
```

> Those afflicted with life try to prevent death.

```
they are afraid of my process and call it wickedness.
```

> Those afflicted with life fear death, and ascribe malice and evil to it.

Comment: Please explain elaborately. Unexplained answers may be deleted.

Comment: @CulverKwan "may be deleted" is a serious statement.

Comment: It has the knowledge tag. The concept of **** is quite well known I believe..

Comment: a good interpretation but not the answer I had in mind, in my riddle the mask and locked up were literally meant not figuratively, but I do understand your thinking :) also as CG. stated the concept of death is well known and probably won't need external sources.